# Trying to get property of non-object. Displaying specific value Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My table looks like

```
name     column1    column2
 p1        2           3
 p2        4           6
```

What I want only to display in my View page is

```
2
```

In my Controller page:

```
public function table(){

$this->load->model('table_model');

$data['value']= $this->table_model->getData();
$this->load->view('table', $data);

}
```

In my Model page:

```
public function getData(){

$this->db->select(*);
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where("name = 'p1'");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

In my View page: I tried

```
   <?php echo $value->column1; ?>
```

but gives me an error

```
 Message: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Answer (score 0):

`$query->result()` returns an array of rows.
If you're looking for just the first row use `return $query->row();` or `$value[0]->column1`.

Edit for example:

`$query->result()` returns:

```
Array (
    [0] => Object (
        name => p1
        column1 => 2
        column2 => 9
    )
)
```

`$query->row()` returns:

```
Object (
    name => p1
    column1 => 2
    column2 => 9
)
```

Comment: I think they're just the same when I put where clause?

Comment: Yes, it only gets one row with the where clause, but the data is returned differently between row() and result(). See my edit for an example.

Answer (score 0):

if your model using `return $query->result()` use `<?php echo $value[0]->column1; ?>`

if your model using `return $query->row()` use `<?php echo $value->column1; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Model-

```
public function getData(){

 $this->db->select(*);
 $this->db->from('table');
 $this->db->where("name = 'p1'");
 $query = $this->db->get();
 $data = $query->result();
 foreach($data as $row){
   $value = $row->column1;
 } 
 return $value; 
}
```

view-
`<?php echo $value; ?>`

Controller-

```
public function table(){

$this->load->model('table_model');

$data['value']= $this->table_model->getData();
$this->load->view('table', $data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Model:

```
public function getData($p1){

$this->db->where('name = p1'); // you can use this or this $this->db->where('name',$p1);
$query = $this->db->get('table');
return $query->result(); // if you use result() you will use in the view is foreach to display the data but if you use row() you can directly call the data i will give example
}
```

Controller:

```
public function table(){

$this->load->model('table_model');

$data['value']= $this->table_model->getData();
$this->load->view('table', $data);

}
```

View:

in using row()

```
<?=$value->column;?> //try this or
<?=echo $value->column; ?>
```

in using result()

```
<?php foreach($value as $val) : ?>
   <tr>
     <td><?=$val->column;?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```